# Comparing two dataframes and store data using R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a dataframe (model_trin_data_df) having 2986 observations of 645 variables and another dataframe (input_data_df) having 1 observation of 6 variables.Where **model_trin_data_df** contains all the 6 variables of **input_data_df**.
Now I want to create another dataframe by comparing both the dataframes where all the variables will be there (i.e 2992 observations) with only one observation.

```
> input_data_df
  blue red white black green gold
   1     1    1      3    1    1

> train_data_df
  bat blue red ball come white black cow green tiger gold go 
  1   2    0    1   0     0    1    0    0     0    0    1
  0   0    0    0   0     1    0    2    0     0    1    0

Out out dataframe should be like -     
    > output_data_df
     bat blue red ball come white black cow green tiger gold go 
     0   1    1    0   0     1    3    0    1     0    1    0
```

I am not worried about the observation of the **train_data_df**. 
What I need is the **output_data_df** contains all the observations of **input_data_df** properly and 0 for rest of the variables.

How I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand your question. The issue is that you want to `append` the model_train_data_df together with model_train_data_df and create a new `data.frame`?

Comment: Do you just want to expand your data to include all variables found in train_data_df, and fill those with zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# data
input_data <- data.frame(blue=1, red=1, white=1, black=3, green=1, gold=1)
train_data <- data.frame(bat=c(1,0),
                         blue=c(2,0),
                         red=c(0,0),
                         ball=c(1,0),
                         black=c(1,0))

# this gives answer
output_df <- sapply(colnames(train_data), function(x){

    if(x %in% colnames(input_data)) return (input_data[,x])
    else return (0)

}, USE.NAMES = F)

# set names
names(output_df) <- names(train_data)

print(output_df)

bat  blue   red  ball black 
 0     1     1     0     3
```

Comment: Glad could help! (